# JS dynamically access & delete nested object property

Tags: javascript, object

I wrote a function to delete a property of a nested object dynamically, based on the given "path" to the property and the "key" it self.

Apparently my code is not dynamic enough because i using the `if` which is not dynamic enough. And it only support the defined dept of object (by the number of if

i would need your professional advise to correct my code:

**Below is the code:**

```
var deleteProp = function (path, prop) {
    console.log(path)
    let keys = path.split('.');
    console.log(keys)
    if(keys.length == 1){
      delete object[keys[0]]
    }
    if(keys.length == 2){
      delete object[keys[0]][keys[1]]
    }
    if(keys.length == 3){
      delete object[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]]
    }
    if(keys.length == 4){
      delete object[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]]
    }
  }
```

A little **side info**, i did refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890239/how-to-delete-nested-json-key-dynamically) but the `let parent = keys.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key], jsonObj);` doesn't work as expected. The value of `parent` some how become one of the key's value instead of construct the "path" for me(which i have no idea why). This is how i implement the code from that post:

```
var deleteProp = function (path, prop) {
    console.log(path)
    let keys = path.split('.');
    console.log(keys)
    let parent = keys.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key], jsonObj) //jsonObj is the nested JSON.
    console.log(parent) // show the value of the key only
    delete parent[prop]
}
```

For those who dono what is **nested object**, please refer to this sample:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: {
      aa: 1,
      bb: 2,
      cc: 3
    }
  },
  e:4,
  f:{
    dd:1,
    ee:2,
    ff:3,
    gg:{
      xx:1,
      yy:2,
      zz:3
    }
  },
  g:[
    {a:1},
    {b:2},
    {c:3}
  ]
};
```

**For those who curious why i want to do so:** 
Because i have a function that will return me a path like `"a.f.gg"` as a string when i lookup for `"yy"`. After i got the path and the property then now i want to delete it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side note: Your question has no JSON, and nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have is just objects and arrays.

Comment: At *least* related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: *"This is how i implement the code from that post"* It was *already* implemented, correctly, in that answer. Your code is *different* from the correct implementation, which is why it doesn't work (in particular, you're not popping the last key off before the `reduce` and then using it afterward). I suggest going back and studying that answer more closely.

Comment: thanks for pointing the "json" mistake, i just removed it.

Comment: and thanks for reminding the `pop()`, i miss it out.